# android Filter result from AsyncTask

Tags: android, android-asynctask, progressdialog, android-alertdialog

Is there a way to filter the results of the AsyncTask while inside the `onPostExecute` method? I was planning to display a MultipleChoice-property AlertDialog.Builder to filter-out the results without ending or dismissing the ProgressDialog.

Here is the process I wanted to do.

```
AsyncTask.onPreExecute
- show ProgressDialog
AsyncTask.doInBackground
- scan all files on `Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().listFiles()`
AsyncTask.onPostExecute
- filter the result parameter (this can be passed to another method of the Activity class or the AsyncTask class)
  - display AlertDialog.Builder with multiple selection property (for example, file extension names)
  - wait to finish selection on the shown AlertDialog.Builder
  - display AlertDialog.Builder with multiple selection property (for example, file directories)
  - wait to finish selection on the shown AlertDialog.Builder
] // do something with the filtered result
] dismiss ProgressDialog
```

---

UPDATE Feb. 06, 2013:

- Update the process done by the said `AsyncTask`.
- The filter process can be placed as another method within the Activity class file.

Comment: After reviewing your update, I concluded that you have two options `Filter files with an extension`  and `Filter file with directory`. Do you want only one option to do OR both one by one?

Comment: One at a time if possible. But as said above, the filter is, as much as possible, done in the `onPostExecute` method not during the `doInBackground` method.

Comment: @PankajKumar: I have updated my question. This maybe hard, I've tried but displaying another Dialog while the ProgressDialog won't do the trick. If I can only get the `result` parameter of the `onPostExecute` on hold for me to filter in it, it may do the trick.